# I have update users table schema but the AuthComponent::user() is not updated in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have updated users table schema but the `AuthComponent::user()` is not updated or the new column I added is not shown (only old columns are shown). How will I update it?

Comment: as you have changed your columns it would be better to just logout and login if it is development phase(it must be in a development / maintainance mode for table columns edit), for normal update use the below answer

Comment: Clearing cache is not working for me, I think Catalin Munteanu got me but if there are other answers, I'd like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthComponent` caches the user data in the session. This data is not refreshed until the user logs in again.

So after any update of the logged in user you should update the session:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id', AuthComponent::user('id'))
));

$this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user);
```

Comment: Thank you all. But I have found solution. It is just because I have getUserByEmail() function in User Model, I don't know but it overrides AuthComponent::user() function, and I have to edit that function to show what I want there. I'll accept your answer because that is the best answer I got here.